# Host command tries several servers

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network, pfsense

I have a DNS server (pfSense) for my LAN, working perfectly, but some timeouts occur that I can't explain. Especially the "host" command gives the correct answer immediately, but then tries 2 times more with timeouts:

```
charles3@cluj:~ » host -v cluj.int.acme.fr
Trying "cluj.int.acme.fr"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14189
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cluj.int.acme.fr.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cluj.int.acme.fr.   1   IN  A   192.168.1.113

Received 52 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53 in 0 ms
Trying "cluj.int.acme.fr"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Trying "cluj.int.acme.fr"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

The timeouts happens during last 4 lines of the output. This happens on the two different machines I have (Mac and Linux).

How can I know why are there two trials while answer has already been given?

Comment: Any rules about DNS queries (53) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete answer from `host` could include IPv6 addresses.  `strace -f host` on Linux suggest these arrive in a separate packet.

It looks like host also queries MX addresses (`kernel.org mail is handled by 30 ns4.kernel.org.`), which requires another packet.

So that would explain how you can have two more requests after the first one.  I.e. the first-level question, of how this is even possible :).

Dnsmasq used on consumer routers used to have a bug, triggered by the pattern of simultaneous ipv4/ipv6 queries used by the polipo web proxy, and the ipv6 result.  I think the second query was ignored & timed out.

I don't know what else would tend to cause this.  A working local resolver should be returning `SERVFAIL` if necessary.  Hopefully pfsense support forums would know more.

You could confirm / narrow it down slightly

```
# ipv4 only
host -t A cluj.int.acme.fr

# simulate the 3 default queries with separate instances
for type in A AAAA MX; do host -t $type cluj.int.acme.fr; done
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed that's what happen, AAAA and MX requests time out. Will ask pfSense guys.

Answer (score 1):

`man host`

> The -a (all) option is equivalent to setting the -v option and asking
>   host to make a query of type ANY.

Better use `-a` option if you want to perform an ANY request because `-v` sends several queries.

`host -a example.com`

```
IP 10.104.11.40.53236 > 10.104.254.250.domain: 36007+ **ANY?** example.com. (28)
IP 10.104.254.250.domain > 10.104.11.40.53236: 36007 3/0/2 A 93.184.216.34, MX mail.example.com. 10, AAAA 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 (137)
```

`host -v example.com`

```
IP 10.104.11.40.62407 > 10.104.254.250.domain: 50385+ **A?** example.com. (28)
IP 10.104.254.250.domain > 10.104.11.40.62407: 50385 1/0/0 A 93.184.216.34 (44)
IP 10.104.11.40.57813 > 10.104.254.250.domain: 42995+ **AAAA?** example.com. (28)
IP 10.104.254.250.domain > 10.104.11.40.57813: 42995 1/0/0 AAAA 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 (56)
IP 10.104.11.40.62687 > 10.104.254.250.domain: 8222+ **MX?** example.com. (28)
IP 10.104.254.250.domain > 10.104.11.40.62687: 8222 1/0/2 MX mail.example.com. 10 (93)
```

Check your firewall if there is any rules that can block sequential DNS queries (port 53).

Comment: I guess you're suggesting a firewall rate-limiting rule as one possibility.